# Use regex to convert ":" into " : " without stripping out line breaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to use regex inside of the textarea in order to strip out or add white space, such that whenever it findds ":" it will be converted to " : " (a space added on each side).

I currently have the following code, which works in [this regex site](https://www.regex101.com/), but is giving me the error message `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?=\n)\s{0,}:\s{0,}(?<=\n)/: Invalid group` :

```
$('textarea[name="yaml"]').val(
  $('textarea[name="yaml"]').val().replace(/(?=\n)\s{0,}:\s{0,}(?<=\n)/ig,
    " : "));
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused - do you just want to find all cases of a single colon and replace them with a spaced colon? I don't think you'll need to worry about newline characters if it's just that.

Comment: @DavidHughes for some reason it was stripping out the new lines when I added it as follows: `\s{0,}:\s{0,}/ig`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having problems because `\s` matches many kinds of spaces including the newline character which you do not want to match. You are seeing errors because you are using regex features that the js regular expression engine you have in your browser does not support.

To preserve newlines, try just using `\x20` instead of `\s`, i.e. matching the exact character for the word space and not just generic whitespace. It should be sufficient to simply do:

```
$('textarea[name="yaml"]').val(
  $('textarea[name="yaml"]').val().replace(/\x20*:\x20*/g, " : ")
);
```

**However** beware that any regex solution could also replace genuine ":" in YAML values as well as just in places where the whitespace doesn't matter. I have no idea if this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

As shown by the demo below, `string.replace(/:/g, ' : ')` should do it:

```js
var str = 'duufuduiure:0ee938:\ndjiedj\n\r:dhdhhiekd\r\ndjdfd;:';
$('pre.before').text( str );
$('pre.after').text( str.replace(/:/g, ' : ') );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
before: <pre class="before"></pre>
after: <pre class="after"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$` end of input character to help with this, if you also use the `m` multiline flag.

```
var foo = "Hello world   : \nmore text here";
foo.replace(/\s*:\s*$/igm, ' : ');
/* console output: 
> "Hello world : 
> more text here"
*/
```